# Using Angular Material with strict Content Security Policy

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styles, content-security-policy

I'm developing an enterprise application using Angular 6 with Angular Material 6.

Now I have to build the project for a new customer that have very strict CSP, that is just

**Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'self';"**

The policy cannot be modified.

I searched for previous answers but only came with the fact of moving my components styles from stylesUrls to the styles property in the angular.json. But even doing so, I still have many errors

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('...'), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

I noticed that when the application starts a lot of < style > tags are added to the head of the page by the compiler, and I think that this is the reason of those repeated errors.

[Styles tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVoC.png)

The meta tag for the Content-Security-Policy is added by me and its only use is to simulate the services response header.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? To build all the css in one single file and add it as a < link > tag when the application is loaded?

**EDIT:**

I found a way to get this working by removing all the stylesUrl from the components and by importing the components stylesheet into the main style.scss.
Then I manually copied everything that was into those style tags into a a css file. Finally I simply linked this css file in my index.html.

The errors in the console have still remained but the application is working correctly.