# Content Security Policy with Angular >= 8

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

How to correctly implement CSP (Content Security Policy) with Angular >= 8?

**I tried something like:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self';" />
```

**On the console, I get the following errors:**

[image]

**To compile I've used the options below without success:**

`npm build --prod` `npm run build --prod` `npm build --aot --prod`

Comment: Change the content of the meta in `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self';`

Comment: In this way, am I not invalidating security? I'm trying to raise the grade at: https://securityheaders.com/

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I encountered the same problem. I solved it like I wrote in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654694/using-angular-material-with-strict-content-security-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654694/using-angular-material-with-strict-content-security-policy).

Comment: Can we conclude that these security policies are currently not supported?

Comment: Yes they are supported but you have to work in a slightly different way to get them working. Like I said in the previous answer you have to import all the styles in a single css file and remove all the <script> tags. After some work I managed to get my project running.

Comment: addStyles.js doesn't look like something built by angular. try to refactor your code to work within the framework

Comment: Related issue with `style-src` requiring `unsafe-inline`: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6361

Comment: Do you use frameworks css (like Bootstrap, Material...)?

Answer (score 2):

you can set your own source beside 'self' source specialy for fonts and icones

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://kit.fontawesome.com 'nonce-YLMZop38Ktla8/hmmA==' 'unsafe-eval' ;style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.syncfusion.com; ">
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is create a web.config file in src the file should contain the below. then you build the file so it is in your dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
<add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://yoururl.com;" />
<add name="Permissions-Policy" value="fullscreen=()"/>
<add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
<add name="Cache-control" value="no-store" />
<add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score -5):

Add the meta tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="YOUR_CSP">
```

in the head of the index.html file

Comment: The question was not about how and where to place the CSP meta tag.